# SQL matching most similar records across 2 datasets without keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 large (100k & 3m) datasets in SQL server and I am trying to match each record in a to the most similar record in b with a couple of conditions including a date condition. I have a mix of continuous and categorical fields on which to match and I wanted to create a score of closeness.

My plan was to create a score of closeness for each possible combination and choose the best scoring record in b for each record in A.
The score is a combination of the closeness in percentiles for the continuous fields and the size for the category for the categorical fields. Additionally any potential matched have to be part of the same class and within 2 weeks of each other.

I tried something like

```
select   a.Key1
    ,a.Key2
    ,a.Value A_Value
    ,b.Value as B_Value
    ,b.Matching_Options

into [DB - Pricing].[dbo].[SL_OB_Match_LC_ALL_Matched]
from ##Table_A as a
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 Value 
    ,count(*) as Matching_Options       
       FROM ##Table_B
    where 
    a.Class=Class
    and abs(datediff(dd,a.Date,Date))<=14
       ORDER BY  
    IIF(a.CAT1=CAT1,1-rnw.CAT1_PCT,0)+IIF(a.CAT2=CAT2,1-rnw.CAT2_PCT,0)+
    1-ABS(a.Cont1_PCT-Cont1_PCT)+1-ABS(a.Cont2_PCT-Cont2_PCT)
        desc
        ) AS b
```

but I'm getting the error

> Column '##Table_B.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm not grouping by anything so this error isn't making sense to me.

The tables are a fair size so efficiency in an answer is important.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add group by because you are using COUNT() aggregate function in cross apply nested query.

```sql
select   a.Key1
    ,a.Key2
    ,a.Value A_Value
    ,b.Value as B_Value
    ,b.Matching_Options

into [DB - Pricing].[dbo].[SL_OB_Match_LC_ALL_Matched]
from ##Table_A as a
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 Value 
    ,count(*) as Matching_Options       
       FROM ##Table_B
    where 
    a.Class=Class
    and abs(datediff(dd,a.Date,Date))<=14
    GROUP BY Value
       ORDER BY  
    IIF(a.CAT1=CAT1,1-rnw.CAT1_PCT,0)+IIF(a.CAT2=CAT2,1-rnw.CAT2_PCT,0)+
    1-ABS(a.Cont1_PCT-Cont1_PCT)+1-ABS(a.Cont2_PCT-Cont2_PCT)
        desc
        ) AS b
```

Comment: thank you! I've pulled it out into a separate cross apply and that seems to be working.